# Question on Discrete metric space

Tags: analysis

Let $X = \{1,1/2,1/4,...,1/2^n,...\} \cup \{0\}$ and $Y = \{X\} - \{0\}$. 
Is $Y$ dense in $X$? The metric is the usual. If yes, why a separable discrete metric space is then countable? In this setting $X$ is not discrete? We cannot have accumulation points in discrete spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $Y$ is dense in $X$.

I don't understand why this answer leads to your other question, but I will answer it. The only dense subset of a discrete metric space is the whole space.  Therefore if the space is separable and discrete, it must be countable.

Comment: So $X$ above is not discrete? The singletons cannot be accumulation points?

Comment: @user61581: Right, in a discrete space every subset is open, and $\{0\}$ is not open in $X$. Every open set containing $\{0\}$ contains infinitely many elements of $Y$.  But $Y$ *is* discrete.